# how to get all sessions in jetty servlet with hazelcast session replication?

Tags: session, jetty, hazelcast, embedded-jetty

my application is based on embedded-jetty with session replication using hazelcast.

In a periodic job We would like to have all sessions currently active to process/send them to another microservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are stored in an [IMap](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html)

You can set the name for this with the `map-name` property for the web filter.

So if this parameter is set the same across all web applications, you'll find all the sessions in the one `IMap`.

If it makes sense for your use-case, you could store the sessions for one application in one `IMap` and for other applications in another `IMap`. They don't have to be all together, though usually that's easiest.

Comment: I have another scenario where i want to invalidate the HttpSessions from this job. Since IMap contains SessionData and not HttpSession how to invalidate them through hazelcast?

Comment: Probably this is best raised as a separate but linked question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534650/how-to-invalidate-sessions-in-jetty-hazelcast

Answer (score 0):

Is that microservice also using hazelcast embedded? If so it can form a cluster with your application's hazelcast instance hence data automatically will be shared. Please note that all hazelcast instances should be within the same LAN to get the best performance and stability out of your cluster.

If microservice is in a remote network, than Hazelcast offers [WAN Replication](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/WAN_Replication/Defining_WAN_Replication.html) to replicate your data to a 2nd cluster. Please remember that this is an enterprise offering though.

Comment: no they are not sharing hazelcast instance. but thanks for answering the question