# how to invalidate sessions in jetty Hazelcast?

Tags: session, jetty, apache-zookeeper, hazelcast, embedded-jetty

I am using hazelcast 3.6.3 in jetty 9.4.8 for session replication and we would like to invalidate multiple sessions based on a separate JMS message.

the hazelcast config is (using zookeeper for peer discovery)

```
Config config = new Config();
    config.setInstanceName(HAZELCAST_INSTANCE_NAME);
    // logger config
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j");
    // config for session map
    MapConfig sessionMapConfig = new MapConfig();
    sessionMapConfig.setName(SESSION_MAP_NAME)
            .setBackupCount(2);
    config.addMapConfig(sessionMapConfig);
    // peer discovery with zookeeper
    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    config.setProperty(GroupProperty.DISCOVERY_SPI_ENABLED, "true");

    DiscoveryStrategyConfig discoveryStrategyConfig = new DiscoveryStrategyConfig(new ZookeeperDiscoveryStrategyFactory());
    discoveryStrategyConfig.addProperty(ZookeeperDiscoveryProperties.ZOOKEEPER_URL.key(), serviceDiscoveryNode);
    discoveryStrategyConfig.addProperty(ZookeeperDiscoveryProperties.ZOOKEEPER_PATH.key(), "sessionstore/APP");
    discoveryStrategyConfig.addProperty(ZookeeperDiscoveryProperties.GROUP.key(), "cluster-name");
    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getDiscoveryConfig().addDiscoveryStrategyConfig(discoveryStrategyConfig);
```

in a job I called

```
Session session = sessionHandler.getSession(id);
session.invalidate(); // or sessionHandler.invalidate(id)
```

but this does not invalidate the session on all instances. Why is that ?

do we need to invalidate session on all instances?

Comment: Can you share the jetty version, hazelcast-jetty-sessionmanager version & related config so I can help?

Comment: i updated question with more details. Thanks!